# Генерация случайной последовательности чисел в Python с помощью тире

Tags: python

Необходимо составить случайную последовательность чисел в Python через тире, например, 46417635-7485-8418-8754-651578178453.

С помощью модуля случайных чисел и функции randint удалось сгенерировать числа в определенном интервале (str(random.randint(100, 150). Как составить последовательность чисел, разделенных дефисом?

Comment: Вы это создаёте? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID

Answer (score 3):

Генерим 36 цифр, на определенных позициях заменяем их дефисами; склеиваем.

```
import random

id = ''.join((c, '-')[i in (8, 13, 18, 23)] for i, c in enumerate(random.choices('0123456789', k=36)))
print(id)
```

```
16206957-4444-6542-7460-863548660777
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто соедините через нужный вам разделитель ваши числа-строки с помощью `str.join`:

```py
import random

numbers = [str(random.randint(100, 150)) for _ in range(5)]
result = '-'.join(numbers)
print(result)
```

Пример вывода:

```
139-129-137-117-141
```

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/YrZVde

```
from uuid import uuid4
 
print(uuid4())
```

```
7bb59495-a4a4-442d-8133-f70611bca5fc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
print("".join(random.choices('-01234567890',k=40)))
```

Можете модифицировать, чтобы тире не было в начале и в конце, два подряд не повторялось, а можно просто заново генерировать, пока не получится хорошо.

Comment: Кажется, в вопросе фиксированые группы, кратные четырем: 8-4-4-4-12. Структура как в https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID .

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я заметил, но это автор явным образом не указал, и шестнадцатиричных цифр не использовано.

Comment: Автор, кажется, не очень осведомлён о задаче которую решает. :)

Answer (score 0):

Составляй 5 чисел нужной длины и соединяй через дефис.